# Python. Как в двумерном массиве вывести тот, который имеет максимальное значение по 1 элементу и минимальное по 2?

Tags: python, массивы

Нужно вывести массив, который имеет максимальное значение по 1 элементу и минимальное по 2.

### `a=[10, 1500], [10, 1200], [8, 1200], [6, 750]]`

`[10, 1200]`

Или

`[[15, 2100], [10, 1500], [10, 1200], [8, 1200], [6, 750]]` -> `[15,2100]`

Answer (score 2):

Используйте функцию max, которой можно указать ключ для сравнения

```
key=lambda x: x[0],-x[1]
```